# Magento changes in static block not reflected in front end

Tags: magento, content-management-system, footer, static-block

I have edited the footer names not the links themselves (dont want them in English but rather in Swedish) however, the changes made in the cms static block does not reflect what visitors see in the front end. I have ensured that the store view (only have one store) is correct and that it is indeed activated. I also cleared the cache both trough admin panel as well as var/cache file.  Yet it is still not working.I would be very great full for any help I receive.

Here is the code for the footer static block:

```
<div class="block-title"><strong>Company</strong></div>
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}about-magento-demo-store/">Om oss</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}contacts/">Kontakta oss</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}customer-service/">Kundservice</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/">Integritetspolicy</a>
<div class="tw-ta-container tw-nfl" id="tw-target-text-container">
<pre class="tw-data-text tw-ta tw-text-medium" dir="ltr" id="tw-target-text" data-placeholder="&Ouml;vers&auml;ttning" data-fulltext=""><span lang="sv">&nbsp;</span></pre>
<p><span lang="sv">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```